# MySQL left join and group by

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables, one of football matches, one of goals. I'm trying to do a select with a left join between the two, counting the number of home and away goals scored. Tables are like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `matches` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `home_team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `away_team_id` int(11) NOT NULL
    ...

CREATE TABLE `match_goals` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `minute` int(11) NOT NULL
    ...
```

and to add all the home team's goals, I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT id, home_team_id, away_team_id from matches) m, 
    (SELECT count(*) AS score, match_id, team_id from match_goals group by match_id, team_id) g 
WHERE m.home_team_id = g.team_id
ORDER by m.id
```

This should bring back one row with the team's score, which could ba positive integer or 0 (or null).

So far I have failed to achieve this - no row is returned if no goal was scored. What am I doing wrong?! Any help much appreciated (or links to other questions - I've look through a lot but haven't found anything I've managed to adapt).

Thanks!

Toby

Comment: Post up a sqlfiddle and desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be easiest with correlated subqueries, rather than explicit `left join`:

```
select m.*,
       (select count(*)
        from match_goals mg
        where mg.match_id = m.id and mg.team_id = m.home_team_id
       ) as home_goals,
       (select count(*)
        from match_goals mg
        where mg.match_id = m.id and mg.team_id = m.away_team_id
       ) as away_goals
from matches m;
```

Comment: I think this does exactly what I want,simple too - great stuff, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
select m.id match_id, home_team_goal, away_team_goal
from matches m left join 
 ( select team_id, match_id, count(*) as home_team_goal
   from match_goals
   group by match_id,team_id
 ) hg on m.id=hg.match_id and m.home_team_id=hg.team_id
  left join 
 ( select team_id, match_id, count(*) as away_team_goal
   from match_goals
   group by match_id,team_id
 ) ag on m.id=ag.match_id and m.away_team_id=ag.team_id
```

[**Working SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/960b12/2)

Answer (score 0):

If we will look on the [SQL left join syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp):

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

If you want both home and away teams score you'll need to do 2 joins.

For only the home teams score your query will look something like this:

```
Select * 
FROM matches as m
LEFT JOIN ( 
   SELECT match_id, team_id, count(*) as count
     from match_goals
   GROUP BY match_id,team_id) as mg)

ON m.id = mg.match_id and m.home_team_id = mg.team_id
```